# Grid of resizable elements with jQuery - are there any libraries that would support this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking to create a 3x3 grid of elements, fixed inside of a larger parent element, that are all resizable. The catch is that I want all 9 child elements to always occupy exactly 100% of the space of the parent. So if I increase the width of the element in the top-left corner, then the two elements on the same row should decrease in size to accommodate this. For instance,

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

In the above grid, let's assume that each letter is 30px by 30px. If I drag-resize A and increase the width to 60px, then I would expect B and C to each decrease by 15 px.

Obviously this can be accomplished using native jQuery UI. Setting a containment parameter on each of the children in the resizable() initialization would take care of binding them all within the parent. The resize event that is fired whenever an element changes could also be examined to determine when each neighboring child might need to move. The thing is, this would be a fairly complex algorithm. It's doable, but it's a lot of work. Before I reinvent the wheel, I wanted to see if a library/plugin that would support this task exists, or anyone has knowledge of a similar open-source project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havent seen such a framework, but sound like an interesting idea.
Alot of things to consider though, like how should the other letters act accordingly?

Played a little:

```
    $('.row div:odd').css('background','blue');

    $('div').click(function(){

        var orgWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).width(orgWidth+100);

        var gridwith = $(this).parent().width();
        var columns = 3;
        var importantClass = '.'+$(this).attr('class');
        var resizeTo = $(this).width();

        var columnsWidth = (gridwith-resizeTo)/(columns-1);

        $(this).parent().children().not(importantClass).width(columnsWidth);

        return false;
    });
```

And

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col4"></div>
    <div class="col5"></div>
    <div class="col6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col7"></div>
    <div class="col8"></div>
    <div class="col9"></div>
</div>
```

And

```
    .row {width:600px; overflow:auto; divst-style:none;}
    .row div {float:left; width:200px; height:200px; background:red;}
    .row div.odd {background:blue;}
```

How would that function into what ur consindering?